# Eclipse indigo 3.7 Pleiades interface language

Tags: eclipse, locale

I want my eclipse to have English user interface, what should I do?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220837/how-to-choose-the-eclipse-interface-language) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770598/how-to-force-eclipse-to-use-a-specified-interface-language), it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eclipse.ini should contain following line:

-Duser.language=en_US

From here :
[How to force eclipse to use a specified interface language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770598/how-to-force-eclipse-to-use-a-specified-interface-language)

And here: [how to change the display language in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492839/how-to-change-the-display-language-in-eclipse)

Comment: if you follow the links in my post, you figure out that I have tried this and it didn't work

Comment: Ah my apologies. Out of curiosity have you tried both "en" and "en_US" ?

Comment: Yes, I did. If I delete eclipse.ini whatsoever, the interface becomes English...partially. One half if it. The other half is still Japanese gibberish

Comment: I'm afraid Pleiades is Japanese-only project, so maybe I am doomed

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and it worked (just translate the page for the instructions)

[translator](http://makotojun.blog52.fc2.com/blog-entry-5.html)